# ToDictionnary() from List in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, type-conversion

I want to use linq to get Dictionnary from a List in c# i use this code

```
List<Jointure> lj = table.jointures.GetJointures(Visibilites.Liste, false)
                        .ConvertAll(o => new Jointure(o, table.nom, tabloidConfig.config.tables[o.nomTable].corbeille));

jointures=new Dictionary<string,Jointure>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

jointures = lj.ToDictionnary(o => o.nom, o => o);
```

But it throws the following exception:

> Erreur    109 'System.Collections.Generic.List' ne
>   contient pas une définition pour 'ToDictionnary' et aucune méthode
>   d'extension 'ToDictionnary' acceptant un premier argument de type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' n'a été trouvée
>   (une directive using ou une référence d'assembly est-elle
>   manquante ?)  D:\dev\Visual
>   studio\Tanloid\Transport\base.aspx.cs 366 32  Tabloid

Answer (score 3):

You spelled the method name incorrectly.  `toDictionnary` should be [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx).

Comment: Sorry may it's to late